# Perl: Matching an array element then copying a PREVIOUS (5 indices back) array element to a new array

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, regular-language, fasta

essentially what I'm trying to do is search through a large text file to identify every element that says " no hits found ", and copy that matches identifier to a new list. I am fine with the first part of this, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to then copy the element of the array exactly 5 indices back (which is an identifier) and copy it to a different array.

I tried something like this,

```
$fastafile = 'HpHcTEST.txt';
open(FASTAFILE, $fastafile);
@seq = <FASTAFILE>;
my $fastaid;
foreach (@seq) {
    if ($_ =~ /\*\*\*\*\* No hits found \*\*\*\*\*/){
        $fastaid .= $_[-5];
    }
}

print "here are the IDs\n";
print $fastaid;
```

with a tonne of variants of the [-5], but none of them worked.. I can't seem find any documentation on how to back reference and attain a previous element if a match is met.
Anyone know how to code for this?

Thank you very much for your time.

Andrew

Answer (score 3):

### A quick fix

One way to do it is to walk over `@seq` with an index.

```
my @fastaid;

for (my $i = 0; $i < @seq; ++$i) {
    if ($seq[$i] =~ /\*\*\*\*\* No hits found \*\*\*\*\*/){
        push @fastaid, $seq[$i - 5] if $i >= 5;
    }
}
```

Note the change away from the scalar to an array named `@fastaid`, which you might print using

```
print "Here are the IDs:\n";
print "  - $_\n" for @fastaid;
```

or even

```
print "Here are the IDs:\n",
      map "  - $_\n", @fastaid;
```

### Adding polish

As [`brian d foy`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8817/brian-d-foy) notes in a comment below, the code could be more elegant and express the intent more directly.

```
my $id_offset = 5;
my @fastaid;

for ($id_offset .. $#seq) {
    if ($seq[$_] =~ /\*\*\*\*\* No hits found \*\*\*\*\*/){
        push @fastaid, $seq[$_ - $id_offset];
    }
}
```

As [documented in the “Scalar Values” section of perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values), `$#seq` is the index or of the last element in `@seq`. The [`..` range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) correctly handles the case where `@seq` is fewer than `$id_offset` elements in length.

The explicit regex-bind operator is still a bit unperlish. You could go with

```
my $id_offset = 5;
my @fastaid;

for my $i ($id_offset .. $#seq) {
  for ($seq[$i]) {
    push @fastaid, $seq[$i - $id_offset]
      if /\*\*\*\*\* No hits found \*\*\*\*\*/;
  }
}
```

or if you have at least version 5.10

```
use feature 'switch';

# ...

my $id_offset = 5;
my @fastaid;

for my $i ($id_offset .. $#seq) {
  given ($seq[$i]) {
    when (/\*\*\*\*\* No hits found \*\*\*\*\*/) {
      push @fastaid, $seq[$i - $id_offset];
    }
  }
}
```

### Historical note

Back in the day, there was some talk of repurposing `$#` to track the index of an array traversal so you could have written

```
for (@fastaid) {
    if (/\*\*\*\*\* No hits found \*\*\*\*\*/) {
        push @fastaid, $seq[$# - 5] if $# >= 5;
    }
}
```

but that never materialized.

Comment: You should probably start at index 5 instead of 0 if you intend to grab five elements back. Otherwise, a match in positions 0 to 4 would grab elements potentially ahead of your position.

Comment: @briandfoy I agree it's a little inelegant, but doesn't the `... if $i >= 5` modifier catch that?

Comment: Ah yes, although I had read your `$#` comment first. Certainly inelegant though. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the indices and subscript to get the array elements:

```
for (5..$#seq) {
    $fastaid .= $seq[$_-5] if $seq[$_] =~ /your_regex/;
}
```

In Perl 5.12 or better you can also use [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html):

```
while (my ($index, $value) = each @seq) {
    next if $index < 5;
    $fastaid .= $seq[$index-5] if $value =~ /your_regex/;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my @fasta_id = map { $seq[$_] =~ /your_regex/ ? $seq[$_-5] : () } 5 .. $#seq;
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a 'for' loop instead of 'foreach',

```
for ($index=0; $index < $#seq + 1; $index++) {
    if ($seq[$index] =~ /\*\*\*\*\* No hits found \*\*\*\*\*/){
        $fastaid .= $seq[$index-5];
    }
}
```

Comment: In Perl, `for` and `foreach` are synonyms that are entirely interchangeable. A more idiomatic comparison is `$index <= $#seq`.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick and helpful feedback!

Comment: In Perl, one might write `for my $index (0 .. $#seq) {`